# How to override ViewModel on calling a page with Shell

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have a call
`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{viewPath}");`
and also defined all the pages with routes and all the viewModels:

```
services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
services.AddSingleton<ItemPage>();
services.AddSingleton<ItemsPage>();
services.AddSingleton<MainPageViewModel>();
services.AddSingleton<ItemPageViewModel>();
services.AddSingleton<ItemsPageViewModel>();
services.AddSingleton<ItemsPageModifiedViewModel>();
```

my idea is to call i.e `ItemsPage` with  `ItemsPageViewModel` which is default, and in some scenarios i want to call `ItemsPage` with `ItemsPageModifiedViewModel` .
Is it possible to override the BindingContext?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static viewmodel for the same model.

I have a shell with tabs of Page1, Page2. And Page 2 has a button to do the navigation.

Page1ViewModel:

```
public  class Page1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _str;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string str
    {
        get
        {
            return _str;
        }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("str");
        }
    }

    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
         
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml:

```
   <Label Text="{Binding str}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Page1 code behind:

```
 public static Page1ViewModel viewmodel { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewmodel = new Page1ViewModel();
        viewmodel.str = "hello";
        this.BindingContext = viewmodel;
    }
```

Page2 code behind:

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page1.viewmodel.str = "test";            
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Page1");
    }
```